# Logging in to my website with Google (what to do after getting access_token)

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

I want to allow my users to have an account on my website using their Google Account to log in (pretty much like on Stack Exchange here). There's a lack of post-2012 guides on this matter on the net so I'm following Google's guides which I find a bit cryptic.

I've successfully followed this guide on [Initiating the Google+ Sign-In flow with JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/javascript-flow) and I can get the access_token with `authResult['access_token']`.

What should I do after this? This access_token is apparently unique and will be different each time the user logs in. Now that my user has logged in using Google+ how can I `POST` a code to my server page to uniquely identify this user and start a PHP session for his account?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `POST` request to your server with the `access_token` so your server can make an authenticated request to [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get). This will return the users Google+ id an optionally their email address you can use to identify them.